# Error when building openssl-1.0.1e on Windows

Tags: openssl, makefile, mingw, msys

I am trying to build openssl-1.0.1e on windows 7 using MSYS.  I did ./config and when I do make, everything seems to go as planned then it gives the error:

```
At top level:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-msys/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/tlhelp32.h:61: error: storage size of 'szExeFile' isn't known
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-msys/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/tlhelp32.h:73: error: storage size of 'szExeFile' isn't known
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-msys/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/tlhelp32.h:94: error: storage size of 'szExePath' isn't known
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-msys/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api/tlhelp32.h:106: error: storage size of 'szExePath' isn't known
make[2]: *** [dso_win32.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/deps/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto/dso'
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/deps/openssl-1.0.1e/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

Can someone help me figure out what this means?

Comment: Normally, msys does not contains any compilers. Did you mean MinGW? Cygwin?

Comment: Well I am using msys to compile things using packages installed through MinGW